# getting errors on simple awk script for-in declaration

Tags: bash, awk

I wrote a simple awk function to print every characters in a array and the compiler is returning the following errors and I don't know what could be wrong.

```
function print_streaks_info(arr) {
    for(index in arr){
        print "starting index: " index
    }
}
```

awk: streak_script.awk: line 2: syntax error at or near in

awk: streak_script.awk: line 5: syntax error at or near }

I didn't try much since i am just starting out with awk and the code is copied and pasted from a tutorial

Comment: According to this loop, you can't have an `in` in a for-loop in `awk`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_loops.htm#

Comment: pretty sure awk supports for-in declarations : https://linuxhint.com/for_loop_awk_command/, I tried to execute this directly on the terminal and it works : `awk 'BEGIN {Customer["4587"] = "Neil Johnson";
Customer["8953"] = "Ella binte Nazir";
Customer["3455"] = "Bruce Hyslop";
Customer["6335"] = "Isabella";
 
}END { for (i in Customer)
print  "The name of ", i, " is " ,Customer[i]
}'`

Comment: `awk` has a string function named `index()`; `awk` appears to be treatring `index` as a reserved word (ie, `awk` is unable to parse this as a call to the `index()` function); try a different name, eg, `for (ndx in arr)`

Comment: @Dominique `for (i in array)` is a very common awk loop construct, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array.

Answer (score 0):

As `mark-fuso` stated in the comments, the issue is your use of the reserved word "**index**", which is a built-in function for searching for patterns in a string.

If you replace your script instances of "**index**" by "**indx**", your script will work without problems.

Below is a demo script incorporating your original function (modified) and using `Carlo Costa's` test array (also modified):

```
#!/bin/bash
    
echo "" |
awk '\
function print_streaks_info(arr){
    for( indx in arr ){
        print "starting index: " indx ;
        break ;
    } ;
}
BEGIN{
    Customer["14587"] = "Neil Johnson" ;
    Customer["8953"] = "Ella binte Nazir" ;
    Customer["23455"] = "Bruce Hyslop" ;
    Customer["6335"] = "Isabella" ;
}
END{
    print_streaks_info(Customer) ;
}'

echo -e "\n NOTE:  The 'in' operator is reporting the array in sequential order of the indexes,\n\t NOT in the order in which they were assigned.\n"
```

Comment: Regarding `The 'in' operator is reporting the array in sequential order of the indexes` - no, it's not. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Scanning-an-Array where it says `The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array elements within awk`. For practical purposes you should consider the order `in` visits array elements as indeterminate and if you see any particular output order for any particular input, consider it a fluke that probably won't be repeated if/when different/addition input provided